Consequences of op amp 1/f noise on the output
I'm looking for an explanation of the consequence of the 1/f noise on an op amp. If, for example, we consider a simple voltage follower with a low noise op amp (but not a zero drift one): what will be the consequence if we observe output voltage during a very long period (several months)?
Could the 1/f noise be interpreted as an offset voltage variation? And could the voltage finish to be very high?
Could this offset be predictable?


What will be the consequence if we observe output voltage during a
very long period (several months)?

There are two things that can cause drift one is 1/f noise and the other is ambient thermal variations. See my answer here: 1/f noise, is it limited?  In silicon 1/f noise is caused by recombination effects of electrons:

A pretty often measurable phenomenon is noise with a spectrum
proportional to 1/f. This leads to the name 1/f noise. Another name is
flicker noise. It is caused essentially by recombination effects at
defects in the semiconductor volume, the borders of diffusion areas or
the material surface.
Source : Noise Modeling for Semiconductors (page 6

So if you observe the output, there will be short term noise variations, and if you don't control the temperature of the device, there will also be thermal variations. If you have tight temperature control, most thermal variations will be reduced.

Could the 1/f noise be interpreted as an offset voltage variation?

No, not if you want to model 1/f noise. It can be considered as a voltage noise source on the output or the input of the opamp, here is an example of a noise analysis on an opamp:

Source: https://kevinfronczak.com/blog/opamp-noise-analysis

Could this offset be predictable?

It can be predictable as far as random processes are predictable (in the same way you can't really predict the output of a random number generator, but you know what the distribution will be), but you can't predict the exact output and subtract out the noise.

Your answer here from 2018 is relevant, I think.

Thanks, forgot about that one.

Thanks a lot Voltage Spike. Spehro 'speff' Pefhany is right : the answer you're provided in 2018 helps me a lot to better understand the phenomena.

Just another question : Horowitz  mention that the integral of the noise power density is log(f), if we trace log(f) the limit when f is near 0 is -infinity ?! what does it mean ?
